# Earliest Available Date - Sum Qty's

Tags: sql, sum, max, sumifs

I am trying to determine the earliest available date for a item. The records below are examples of open purchase order dates.

If an sales order calls for *Qty 150*, the earliest date available would be *2018-09-06*.

If a sales order called for *Qty 160*, the earliest date available would be *2018-09-28*.

Using the statement below will only return the *MAX* date value of *2018-10-01*, is there a way to grab the correct earliest date based on `SUM(po_qty) >= sales_order_qty`?

```
IIF(SUM(po_qty) >= sales_order_qty,MAX(receive_date)) = 2018-10-01


branch item_id  po_qty receive_date
VMXX    93111   50     2018-06-13
VMXX    93111   50     2018-08-02
VMXX    93111   50     2018-09-06
VMXX    93111   100    2018-09-28
VMXX    93111   50     2018-10-01
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In most databases, you would use the ANSI-standard cumulative sum functionality:

```
select min(receive_date)
from (select t.*,
             sum(po_qty) over (partition by branch, item_id order by receive_date) as running_qty
      from t
      where branch = ? and item_id = ?
    ) t
where running_qty >= ?;
```